# Overriding patchAttributes method in Loopback3

Tags: loopbackjs

Can somebody please provide the syntax of how to override patchAttributes method in loopback 3
I am using the following syntax which is not working

```
BUILDING.on('attached', () => {
BUILDING.patchAttributes = (id, data, { }, next) => {
            app.models.AC_BUILDING.patchAttributes(data,(err, res) => {
                next(err, res)
            })
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `patchAttributes` method present on `PersistedModel` object or even its instance. You can check verify the API docs here at http://apidocs.loopback.io/loopback/. I think you might be getting confused with the `updateAttribute` or `updateAttributes` method. If you want to update certain properties on a persisted model, `updateAttribute` or `updateAttributes` is the way to go.